# Apache Camel 2.23.1: to(file) creates an empty file

Tags: apache-camel

[JDK 8 / 11, Camel 2.23.1, Spring Boot 2.1.3]

Hi,
I'm currently learning Camel and I can't get past a strange problem.

I want to download a URL to a file.

The URL works, e.g. http://localhost/date shows "11:59:00".
The target file is created, but it's empty. Why?

```
@Component
public class DownloadRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        String timer1 = "timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=10000&delay=5000";
        String url = "http://localhost:8888/date";
        String file = "file:target/date";
        from(timer1).to(url).log("${id}->${body}").to(file);  // ID-Laptop-1551464093962-0-2->11:59:00, that's ok
    }
}
```

The logger outputs the correct content, e.g.

> 2019-03-01 19:15:00.421  INFO 2984 --- [3 - timer://foo] route1
>   : ID-Laptop-1551464093962-0-2->11:59:00

but the generated file (e.g. target/date/ID-Laptop-1551464093962-0-2) is empty.

Any ideas?

**Solution (thanks to Tache):**

```
    from(timer1).to(url).to(file);  // without logging
```

OR

```
    from(timer1).to(url).convertBodyTo(String.class).log("${id}->${body}").to(file);    // with logging
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of your http endpoint (http://localhost:8888/date) is probably a stream that is read using a InputStream. Such stream can be read only once.
Possible solutions:

- remove your log statement
- enable stream caching in your Camel context or route
- convert message body to a string (`.convertBodyTo(String.class)` ) before logging it and sending it to a file